# .NET Core tools preview for Visual Studio (2015) installation failure

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am reinstalling visual stuido with .net core. I followed the steps stated on the website (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015).

However, during the installation .NET Core tools preview for Visual Studio I am obtaining the following error, which I did not understand. I am admin of the PC. I will be glad if you can suggest solution(s).

Here is the last part of the log file of the installation:

[0864:13D0][2017-01-13T13:35:27]i301: Applying execute package: DotNetCLI_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\packages\DotNetCore.1.0.1-SDK.1.0.0.Preview2-003131-x64.exe" /quiet /norestart'

[0864:13D0][2017-01-13T13:36:22]e000: Error 0x80070490: Process returned error: 0x490

[0864:13D0][2017-01-13T13:36:22]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.

[20FC:2318][2017-01-13T13:36:22]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

[20FC:2318][2017-01-13T13:36:22]i319: Applied execute package: DotNetCLI_x64, result: 0x80070490, restart: None

[20FC:2318][2017-01-13T13:36:22]e000: Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.

[0864:13D0][2017-01-13T13:36:22]i351: Removing cached package: DotNetCLI_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\

[0864:13D0][2017-01-13T13:36:22]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No

[0864:13D0][2017-01-13T13:36:22]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{da280276-4f5b-4918-8d40-20ca56dfa535}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No

[20FC:2318][2017-01-13T13:36:23]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070490, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after trying Visual Studio 2017. The Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) - v 14.10.+ was installed. I removed it and reinstalled v 14.0.x from here https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/F/6DF3FF94-F7F9-4F0B-838C-A328D1A7D0EE/vc_redist.x64.exe - after that I was able to run the installers and get the dotnet cli working again.